# How to reset .table-stripe class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table where i am trying to sort by animal type. I have this all working but for some reason the stripe on the rows is messed up. I can have 2 grey striped rows right on top of each other. [Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4raj5xf/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Get all the rows for the table
    $upcoming = $('#upcoming_production_sales .table');
    $events = $upcoming.find('tr.event');
    map = {};

    // Find the event category column push into map
    $events.each(function(idx,ele){ 
    diffText = $(ele).find('td.event-category').text();
    diffText = (diffText == undefined || diffText == "" ? "Other" : diffText).toLowerCase();
    if(!map[diffText]){
        map[diffText]=[];
    }
    map[diffText].push(ele);
    });

    // Get keys 
keys=Object.keys(map);
    var filterEvents = function filterEvents(diffText) {
      keys.forEach(function(key, idx, arr) {
        var hideRows = (key.toLowerCase() != diffText.toLowerCase()) && ("all" != diffText.toLowerCase());
        map[key].forEach(function(row, idx, arr) {
          if(hideRows) $(row).hide();
          else $(row).show();
        });
      });
    };




    $("#upcoming_production_sales .all-upcoming-events").click(function(event){
        // Remove active class
    $("#upcoming_production_sales .nav li").removeClass('active');
    // Add active class to clicked event
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        filterEvents('all');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#upcoming_production_sales .cattle-upcoming-events").click(function(event){
    $("#upcoming_production_sales .nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        filterEvents('cattle');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#upcoming_production_sales .deer-upcoming-events").click(function(event){
    $("#upcoming_production_sales .nav li").removeClass('active');
    // Add active class to clicked event
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        filterEvents('deer');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#upcoming_production_sales .equine-upcoming-events").click(function(event){
    $("#upcoming_production_sales .nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        filterEvents('equine');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#upcoming_production_sales .goat-upcoming-events").click(function(event){
    $("#upcoming_production_sales .nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        filterEvents('goats');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#upcoming_production_sales .sheep-upcoming-events").click(function(event){
    $("#upcoming_production_sales .nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        filterEvents('sheep');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#upcoming_production_sales .swine-upcoming-events").click(function(event){
    $("#upcoming_production_sales .nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        filterEvents('swine');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#upcoming_production_sales .other-upcoming-events").click(function(event){
    $("#upcoming_production_sales .nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        filterEvents('other');
        event.preventDefault();
    });


});
```

Comment: Please provide a question that we can help you answer.  Also, posting all your code is not helpful.  It's best to break your problem into small parts and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is because the `:nth-child` CSS selector still counts hidden elements. This means you have mismatched stripes on the elements which remain visible. The workaround for this is to use jQuery's `:even` and `:odd` selectors to apply the striping when the filter is amended.

Firstly you need to remove the `table-striped` class from the `table`. Then you can add a function to stripe the rows for you. Try this:

```
keys = Object.keys(map);
var filterEvents = function(diffText) {
    keys.forEach(function(key, idx, arr) {
        var hideRows = (key.toLowerCase() != diffText.toLowerCase()) && ("all" != diffText.toLowerCase());
        map[key].forEach(function(row, idx, arr) {
            if (hideRows) 
                $(row).hide();
            else 
                $(row).show();
        });
        setStripe(); //when the filter is changed
    });
};

var setStripe = function() {
    $(".table tr:visible:odd").addClass('odd').removeClass('even');
    $(".table tr:visible:even").addClass('even').removeClass('odd');
}
setStripe(); // on load
```

Also note that you can DRY up the repeated click handlers you have on the filter `a` element through the use of `data-*` attributes:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a class="all-upcoming-events" href="#" data-filter="all">All Events <span class='badge'>216</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="cattle-upcoming-events" href="#" data-filter="cattle">Cattle <span class='badge'>177</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="deer-upcoming-events" href="#" data-filter="deer">Deer <span class='badge'>6</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="equine-upcoming-events" href="#" data-filter="equine">Equine <span class='badge'>0</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="goat-upcoming-events" href="#" data-filter="goats">Goats <span class='badge'>10</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="sheep-upcoming-events" href="#" data-filter="sheep">Sheep <span class='badge'>0</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="swine-upcoming-events" href="#" data-filter="swine">Swine <span class='badge'>0</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="other-upcoming-events" href="#" data-filter="other">Other <span class='badge'>23</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$("#upcoming_production_sales a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#upcoming_production_sales .nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    filterEvents($(this).data('filter'));
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/g4raj5xf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`Bootstrap` applies the alt color row to the table rows only once during the pageload. Since in your case, you are just hiding the rows which are not relevant, the alt row color would not be consistent. In order to fix it, you need to reply the styles once you are finished filtering the rows.

```
  $('.table-striped tr:nth-child(2n) td').css("background-color","#f9f9f9");
      $('.table-striped tr:nth-child(2n+1) td').css("background-color","#ffffff");
```

Here's the working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/g4raj5xf/1/

Comment: If you click 'Goats' you can see this still has issues. The reason is because the `nth-child` selector does not respect hidden elements.